# PHP redis error

Tags: php, redis

I installed the php redis extension. But when I run the test code, I got the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/redio.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/redio.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Redis' not found in /var/www/test/redisTest.php on line 2
```

My php version is 5.3.10, I installed the new version of phpredis.

May I get your help?
THANKS!

The install steps are:

```
git clone https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis.git
cd phpredis
 phpize
make 
make install
```

Then add a config file in /etc/php5/fpm/confi.d to load redis.so

Comment: `redio.so`? should probably be `redis.so`. Fix the line in your php.ini and things should start working.

Answer (score 9):

I use PHP 5.3 and installing PHP-Redis using below steps worked just fine for me:

- Install pecl extension
  `sudo pecl install redis`
- In `php.ini`, you *may* need set `extension_dir` to correct value. (can be `usr/lib64/php/modules` as above command placed the redis.so in this directory). In my case, I didn't set this.
- Add below line to `php.ini`:
  `extension=redis.so`
- Restart Apache/PHP-FPM

Comment: Is not working, [screenshot contains more info](http://i64.tinypic.com/hsjd5s.png). Error = pecl/redis requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0, version <= 7.1.0, excluded versions: 6.0.0), installed version is 5.5.30. No valid packages found, install failed

Answer (score 9):

To verify if you have got redis installed you can do this

`php -m | grep redis`

Answer (score 3):

Create a file PHP with *echo phpinfo();* in it and see if the module is showing up. If you do not see the module then it is not being loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP5.3 and Amazon Linux AMI (Same as Centos OS 5)

install libs

```
yum install php-pear php-devel make gcc wget
```

install redis

```
cd /opt/
mkdir /opt/redis
wget https://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.6.14.tar.gz "or last version"
tar -zxvf redis-2.6.14.tar.gz
cd redis-2.6.14
make
make install
```

install php-redis by pecl

```
pecl install redis
```

configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location

You should add "extension=redis.so" to php.ini

reload the web service httpd

```
service httpd reload
```

verify that the extension has been installed

```
php -m
[PHP Modules]
bz2
...
**redis**
...
[Zend Modules]
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the proper library file according to your server environment( ex. x86). also, check for your PHP is thread-safe or not and download the Redis library accordingly. then place the library file inside the extension folder. you need to mention the library inside your php.ini as given below.

```
extension=redis.dll
```

then restart the server once, and check it's working properly or not.
if you have command line PHP, you can check it in the command line PHP as,

```
php r("print_r(get_loaded_extensions());")
```